# Regex for finding chains of >=1 words starting with capital letters and connected with "-" or " "

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to obtain all the letter-only "chains" of at least 1 word starting with uppercase letters and followed by lowercase letters, connected with either space (" ") **or** "-" (a "chain" cannot be connected with "-" and with " ")

For example, for the following text:

> For the First Stage, you should press Start and you should follow
> Step-One and Step-Three. For the Final Stage, you must follow the
> sequence of One-Two-Five-Seven Steps

My output should be

> ["For", "First Stage", "Start", "Step-One", "Step-Three", "Final
> Stage", "One-Two-Five-Seven", "Steps"]

Until now, I have tried writing 2 different regexes to solve my problem; first string should return
"chains" connected with "-" and the second should return "chains" connected with " ":

```
import re
list(set(re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+-)*[A-Z][a-z]+', mystring) + re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+ )*[A-Z][a-z]+', mystring)))
```

However, I guess it is something wrong with them, as neither of them is working properly.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z][a-z]+)*', mystring)`. However, what is expected output for `One-Two-Five Seven`? `['One-Two-Five Seven']` or `['One-Two-Five', 'Seven']`?

Comment: The expected output shoud be ['One-Two-Five', 'Seven'].
Sorry for ambiguity, I will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?=([-\s]?))(?:\1[A-Z][a-z]+)*\b(?!-[A-Z])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3hqUSL/3). **Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?=([-\s]?))` - a positive lookahead that requires either a `-` or whitespace char (1 or 0 times, optionally) immediately to the right of the current location, capturing the char into Group 1
- `(?:\1[A-Z][a-z]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\1` - same text as captured in Group 1
  - `[A-Z][a-z]+` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `\b(?!-[A-Z])` - a word boundary not followed with `-` and an uppercase ASCII letter.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pPV5xW):

```py
import re
pattern = r"\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?=([-\s]?))(?:\1[A-Z][a-z]+)*\b(?!-[A-Z])"
text = "For the First Stage, you should press Start and you should follow Step-One and Step-Three. For the Final Stage, you must follow the sequence of steps One-Two-Five Seven // Steps One-Two-Five-Seven"
print( list(set([x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, text)])) )
# => ['Step-Three', 'For', 'First Stage', 'Seven', 'One-Two-Five-Seven', 'Start', 'One-Two-Five', 'Steps', 'Step-One', 'Final Stage']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't give the correct output when a " "-chain is followed by a "-"-chain
For example "Steps One-Two-Five-Seven" returns
["Steps One", "Two-Five-Seven"] instead of ["Steps", "One-Two-Five Seven"]

Comment: @JuanTutrifor Try `\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?=([-\s]?))(?:\1[A-Z][a-z]+)*\b(?!-[A-Z])`

Comment: Stribizew - That's perfect. Edit your answer and I will accept it